# illustrating volatile : is this code thread-safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile

I'm trying to illustrate the use and importance of `volatile` with an example that would really not give a good result if `volatile` was omitted.

But I'm not really used to using `volatile`. The idea of the following code is to cause an infinite loop if `volatile` is omitted, and be perfectly thread-safe if `volatile` is present. Is the following code thread-safe? Do you have any other realistic and short example of code that uses `volatile` and would give an obviously incorrect result without it?

Here's the code:

```
public class VolatileTest implements Runnable {

    private int count;
    private volatile boolean stopped;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!stopped) {
            count++;
        }
        System.out.println("Count 1 = " + count);
    }

    public void stopCounting() {
        stopped = true;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        if (!stopped) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("not stopped yet.");
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        VolatileTest vt = new VolatileTest();
        Thread t = new Thread(vt);
        t.start();
        Thread.sleep(1000L);
        vt.stopCounting();
        System.out.println("Count 2 = " + vt.getCount());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Victor is right, there are issues with your code: atomicity and visibility.

Here's my edition:

```
    private int count;
    private volatile boolean stop;
    private volatile boolean stopped;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!stop) {
            count++; // the work
        }
        stopped = true;
        System.out.println("Count 1 = " + count);
    }

    public void stopCounting() {
        stop = true;
        while(!stopped)
           ; //busy wait; ok in this example
    }

    public int getCount() {
        if (!stopped) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("not stopped yet.");
        }
        return count;
    }

}
```

If a thread observes that `stopped==true`, it's guaranteed that the work completes and the result is visible.

There is a happens-before relation from volatile write to volatile read (on the same variable), so if there are two threads

```
   thread 1              thread 2

   action A
       |
 volatile write  
                  \
                     volatile read
                          |  
                       action B
```

action A happens-before action B; writes in A are visible by B.

Comment: As is, the example is broken, because `count++` is not an atomic operation. You must either acquire a lock around that operation, or use a non-blocking `AtomicInteger`.

Comment: (unless, of course, you make sure that only 1 thread will ever call the method `run()` -- anyways, the code above cannot be claimed to be **thread-safe**)

Answer (score 1):

It was always hard to me to illustrate concurrency problems in a convincing way: well, fine, it's all nice about *happens-before* and stuff, but why should one care? Is there a real problem? There are lots and lots of poorly written, poorly synchronized programs—and they still work most of the time.

I used to find a resort in a "*works most of the time* VS *works*" rhetoric—but, frankly, it's a weak approach. So what I needed is an example which would make difference obvious—and, preferably, painful.

So here is a version which actually does show the difference:

```
public class VolatileExample implements Runnable {
    public static boolean flag = true; // do not try this at home

    public void run() {
        long i = 0;
        while (flag) {
            if (i++ % 10000000000L == 0)
                System.out.println("Waiting  " + System.currentTimeMillis());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new VolatileExample());
        thread.start();
        Thread.sleep(10000L);
        flag = false;
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("stopping " + start);
        thread.join();
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("stopped  " + end);
        System.out.println("Delay: " + ((end - start) / 1000L));
    }
}
```

A simple run shows:

```
Waiting  1319229217263
stopping 1319229227263
Waiting  1319229242728
stopped  1319229242728
Delay: 15
```

That is, it takes *more than ten seconds* (15 here) for a running thread to notice there was *any* change.

With `volatile`, you have:

```
Waiting  1319229288280
stopping 1319229298281
stopped  1319229298281
Delay: 0
```

that is, exiting (almost) immediately. The resolution of `currentTimeMillis` is around 10ms, so the difference is more that 1000 times.

Note it was Apple's version of (ex-)Sun JDK, with `-server` option. The 10-second wait was added in order to let JIT compiler find out that the loop is hot enough, and optimize it.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Simplifying @Elf example further, where the other thread will never get the value which was updated by other thread. Removing System.out.println as there is synchronized code inside println and out is static, somehow that helps the other thread to get the latest value of flag variable.

```
public class VolatileExample implements Runnable {
   public static boolean flag = true; 


  public void run() {
     while (flag);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new VolatileExample());
    thread.start();
    Thread.sleep(1000L);
    flag = false;
    thread.join();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE** My answer is wrong, see answer from irreputable.

---

It's <strike>not</strike> thread-safe, since <strike>access to `count` is not</strike> there's only one writer thread. Should there be another writer thread, value of `count` would be become inconsistent to the number of updates.

Visibility of `count` value to main thread is ensured by checking `stopped` volatile inside `getCount` method. This is what is called `piggybacking on synchronization` in `Concurrency in practice` book.

Comment: int updates are atomic, as per the JLS. However, read/write ordering might be problematic without volatile, when the variable isn't fenced by synchronisation.

Comment: The idea of the exception in getCount is to guarantee that count is only accessed by an external thread once the writes to count are finished. And I thought writing to the volatile variable guaranteed the visibility of count to all the threads. Isn't it right?

Comment: @JBNizet, Why would you think it's alright to modify a field in one thread and expect to get the correct value when reading it from another thread without synchronization?

Comment: @ChrisDennett updates are indeed atomic; the problem is, you read `count`, increment it, and (atomically) write it back. If another thread did the same in the meantime, you may as well end up losing one of the increments.

Comment: Update may be, but code is using ++, which is read-change-store operation.

Comment: @mre it will actually work, since `getCount` checks the same volatile which is used by counting thread and this will ensure visibility of `count` value in main thread.

Comment: @mre : because of the write to the volatile stopped variable, which is a synchronization mechanism. Brian Goetz says, in "Java Concurrency in Practice" : The visibility effects of volatile variables extend beyond the value of the volatile variable itself. When thread A writes to a volatile variable
and subsequently thread B reads that same variable, the values of all variables that were visible to A prior to writing to the volatile variable become visible to B after reading the volatile variable.

Comment: continued : So from a memory visibility perspective, writing a volatile variable is like exiting a synchronized block and reading a volatile variable is like entering asynchronized block.

Comment: @JBNizet exactly the thing I've just looked up in that book :)

Comment: @JBNizet I think, in presence of only one writer it is thread-safe. Should there be another writer thread to `count`, code would become unsafe.

Comment: @Victor @JB  It's not safe. Without a volatile write in the run() thread, the write to `count` may not be flushed; the main thread may observe `0`.

Comment: @irreputable : I think you're right : the counter thread will see the variables from the main thread, but the main thread won't necessarily see the variables from the counter thread. If I understood it correctly, please add this explanation to your own answer, and I'll accept it.

Comment: Thank you all for answering. I knew I would miss something. I'm just glad I'm not the only one :-)

Answer (score 0):

To illustrate the importance of the `volatile` keyword when it comes to concurrency, all you need to do is make sure that the `volatile` field is modified and read in a separate threads.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong code with which we cannot assume x = 1 also if y is already 2:

```
Class Reordering {
  int x = 0, y = 0;
  public void writer() {
    x = 1;
    y = 2;
  }

  public void reader() {
    int r1 = y;
    int r2 = x;
  }
}
```

Example of use of volatile keyword:

```
class VolatileExample {
  int x = 0;
  volatile boolean v = false;
  public void writer() {
    x = 42;
    v = true;
  }

  public void reader() {
    if (v == true) {
      //uses x - guaranteed to see 42.
    }
  }
}
```

Source: http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html