# Regarding volatile variable usage

Tags: java

I am new to the volatile variable but I was going through article which states 2) Volatile variable can be used as an alternative way of achieving synchronization in Java in some cases, like Visibility. with volatile variable its guaranteed that all reader thread will see updated value of volatile variable once write operation  completed, without volatile keyword different reader thread may see different values.

I request you guys could you please show this with me a small java program , so technically also it is clear to me.

what I come from my understanding is...
Volatile means each Thread Access the variable will have its own private copy which is same as original one.But if the Thread is going to change that private copy,then original one will not get reflected.

```
public class Test1 {  
   volatile int i=0,j=0;  
   public void add1()  
           {  
            i++;  
            j++;  
      }  
   public void printing(){  
       System.out.println("i=="+i+ "j=="+j);  
   }  

    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        Test1 t1=new Test1();  
        Test1 t2=new Test1();  
        t1.add1();//for t1 ,i=1,j=1  
        t2.printing();//for t2 value of i and j is still,i=0,j=0  
        t1.printing();//prints the value of i and j for t1,i.e i=1,j=1  
        t2.add1();////for t2 value of i and j is changed to i=1;j=1  
        t2.printing();//prints the value of i and j for t2i=1;j=1  
    }  

}
```

I request you guys could you please show a small program of volatile functionality, so technically also it is clear to me

Answer (score 1):

Volatile variable as you have read guarantees visibility but doesn't guarantee atomicity - another important aspect of thread safety. I will try to explain by an example

```
public class Counter {
   private volatile int counter;

   public int increment() {
       System.out.println("Counter:"+counter); // reading always gives the correct value
       return counter++; // atomicity isn't guaranteed, this will eventually lead to skew/error in the expected value of counter.
   }

   public int decrement() {
       System.out.println("Counter:"+counter);
       return counter++;
   }
}
```

In the example, you can see that the read operation will always give the correct value of counter at an instant of time, however atomic operations (like evaluate a condition and do something and read and write on the basis of read value) thread safety is not guaranteed.

You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851327/illustrating-volatile-is-this-code-thread-safe) answer for additional details.

> Volatile means each Thread Access the variable will have its own
>   private copy which is same as original one.But if the Thread is going
>   to change that private copy,then original one will not get reflected.

I am not sure I understand you correctly, but volatile fields imply they are read and written from the main memory accessible to all threads - there are no thread specific copies (caching) of the variable.

From [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.4),

> A field may be declared volatile, in which case the Java Memory Model
>   ensures that all threads see a consistent value for the variable